# Corrupted file error on .docx files, when downloading them from PHP

Tags: php, phpword

I have a weird problem with downloaded .docx files from my webserver.
I get an corrupted file error, when I try to open the downloaded document.

When I try to download the files manually (via FileZilla) I am able to open them without problems.

```
$targetFile = ASSETS . "/tmp/{$filename}.{$extension}";
ob_clean();
$phpWord->save($targetFile,$format,false);

if(headers_sent())
{
    echo 'http header already sent';die();
}
else{
    if (!is_file($targetFile)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found';die();
    } else if (!is_readable($targetFile)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';die();
    } else {
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".".$extension."");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($targetFile));

        set_time_limit(0);

        readfile($targetFile);

        exit();
   }
}
```

Also running the code on localhost works and I am able to open files without problems.

One thing I observed was that the downloaded document misses 1 kb in size, when I download it via my code, so I'm assuming some content is missing, but can't seem to find the problem.

I can see that many have similar problems and I tried the solutions suggested for those, but without luck.

Any ideas?